# Why we need a request token in a web app?

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, tweepy

I'm following this tutorial http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.0/auth_tutorial.html which explains how to sign-in with Twitter using `tweepy`.

I don't understand the role of the request tokens! If we are able to get the `oauth_verifier` and then do `auth.get_access_token(verifier)`, then what's the purpose of storing the request tokens in sessions and then setting them with `auth.set_request_token(token[0], token[1])`.

My code is the following:

1- `redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()`

2- Redirect the user to that url.

3- Once the user authorize the app from Twitter, then twitter will redirect to my website and has `oauth_verifier` parameter in it.

4- Get the value of the `oauth_verifier` from the URL.

5- Do `auth.get_access_token(verifier)`

6- Now we have the access tokens as:

```
key = auth.access_token.key
secret = auth.access_token.secret
```

So I really can't understand the idea behind the request tokens. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: It may be helpful to review the [OAuth FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) or the [Using OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth) pages for Twitter Developers.